# Comparing two vectors and calculating differences to corresponding elements

Tags: r

I've defined a birth-death process in R, it can be in the states 0,1,2, and 3. I have a vector "state" that lists the order in which the states occur, and another vector "time" that lists at which time these state changes occur.

Let's say that the vectors look something like:

```
state <- c(0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3)
time <- c(0.00, 0.03, 0.12, 0.78, 0.87, 0.94, 0.97, 1.18, 1.23, 1.30)
```

If I wanted to calculate the proportion of time spent in state 1 for example, I could see which elements in "time" correspond to the elements in "state" where "1" occur. And then calculate and summarize the differences between the corresponding and next coming element in the "time" vector, and then divide it by the total time.
How do I write a function that calculates the proportion of time spent in any given state?

Comment: Thanks for including sample data. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is this a homework problem :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the difference between each element to get the time in the corresponding state and then sum over the times ordered by state.

```
state <- c(0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3)
time <- c(0.00, 0.03, 0.12, 0.78, 0.87, 0.94, 0.97, 1.18, 1.23, 1.30)

df <- data.frame(state=state,time=time)
df$diff <- c(diff(df$time),0)

tim.p.state <- data.frame(time=sapply(split(df,df$state),function(df){return(sum(df$diff))}))
tim.p.state$proportion <- tim.p.state$time/time[length(time)]
```